# System.IO.IOException: Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component. Asp.net 7. Using DisableFormDataBinding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Stack-trace:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component. 
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReaderStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.StreamHelperExtensions.DrainAsync(Stream stream, ArrayPool`1 bytePool, Nullable`1 limit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReader.ReadNextSectionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.InnerReadFormAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.ReadForm()
     at Shamazon.Controllers.ProductsController.Upload() in /mnt/wwn-0x5000c500c757436c-part1/Workspace/Shamazon/Controllers/ProductsController.cs:line 19
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
```

Controller Code:

```
[HttpPost("upload")]
[DisableFormValueModelBinding]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload()
{
    Console.WriteLine(HttpContext.Request.Form);

    return StatusCode(202, new { test = "bruh" });
}
```

Attribute Code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute : Attribute, IResourceFilter
{
    public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
    {
        var formValueProviderFactory = context.ValueProviderFactories
            .OfType<FormValueProviderFactory>()
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (formValueProviderFactory != null)
        {
            context.ValueProviderFactories.Remove(formValueProviderFactory);
        }

        var formFileValueProviderFactory = context.ValueProviderFactories
            .OfType<FormFileValueProviderFactory>()
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (formFileValueProviderFactory != null)
        {
            context.ValueProviderFactories.Remove(formFileValueProviderFactory);
        }

        var jqueryFormValueProviderFactory = context.ValueProviderFactories
            .OfType<JQueryFormValueProviderFactory>()
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (jqueryFormValueProviderFactory != null)
        {
            context.ValueProviderFactories.Remove(jqueryFormValueProviderFactory);
        }
    }

    public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Request from front-end in a React app:

```
const request = await fetch("/api/products/upload", {
     method: "POST",
     headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryLhcxqmSmEPRWew71"
     },
     body: JSON.stringify({
          Name: name,
          Description: description,
          Price: price,
          ImageUrl: file
     })
 });
```

I had this problem before I tried the `[DisableFormValueModelBinding]` attribute. All of the solutions to this problem involved `[DisableFormValueModelBinding]` in some capacity, but it just doesn't work for me. I feel like I'm missing something that's staring me in the face, but I'm stumped regardless.

Another question is: if the stream is already read, then where is that data? The stream being read implies that the data is already copied somewhere (assuming the data was copied, because why would you read data just for the sake of reading it and not storing it anywhere). That being said, is there somewhere it could exist that I could pull from? Or could I re-read the stream from the beginning?

Thanks

p.s. I'm using the newest version of ASP.NET (which I think is 7)

p.p.s A strange thing is that when I test the endpoint with Insomnia or with the form's default submission behavior, the form read just fine. I don't have any clue why that would make a difference, but I would really like to use fetch if possible.

Comment: Is it a Web Api Project? I try your action  code in my demo and just get `incorrect content-type` error, Do you have another code like middleware to cause this error?

Comment: @XinranShen I'm using ASP.NET as a back-end to a React app. The reason you are getting incorrect content-type is probably because my payload is a multipart/form-data. I will update post to show the fetch request.

Comment: @XinranShen Also no, no other middleware.